# What does "ano tonari desu" mean?

Tags: meaning

I came across such an answer to a "Where is something?" question:

> Asoko ni takai biru ga arimasune. **Ano tonari desu.**

What does "Ano tonari desu" mean here? Is this a shorthand for "Ano biru no tonari ni ga arimasu"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

あの隣です = It is next door to there

Since the first sentence established the building "next door" as あそこ(の)高いビル, あの is sufficient to specify there to refer to that building.

If you wanted to say it in a single sentence:

> あそこの高いビルの隣です

> It's next to that tall building over there.

Answer (score 2):

"Ano" is just pointing the previously said "building". But it is something like a "genitive case" of the pronoun, something like "of it". So, "ano tonari" is "the vicinity of it (the building)".